# Why are the Image paths for django-ckeditor being set incorrectly?

Tags: django

Basically these are my settings.py settings;

```
MEDIA_ROOT = 'C:/Users/Deep.C/.virtualenvs/projectcontainer/mysite/media/'

MEDIA_URL = '/media/'   

CKEDITOR_UPLOAD_PATH = MEDIA_ROOT
```

Image upload is working within the Rich Text Editor, as the file is turning up in the correct directory.

However when trying to browse images the images are never being loaded due from I assume is the path to the image being incorrect as follows;

```
<img src="/media/2013\06\25\Google-Chrome-icon_thumb.png">
```

It is returning a 404 NOT FOUND. In the console the path being displayed `http://localhost:8080/media/2013/06/25/Google-Chrome-icon_thumb.png`

I know this is a fairly trivial thing probably me not setting things up correctly but i cant seem to figure out where i could have gone wrong.

Any help would be appreciated!

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Static files and files served from media are done through 2 different methods. In order for the media files to be served you need to serve files from the media folder. To do so follow the guide at https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/howto/static-files/

The section you are interested in is "Serving files uploaded by a user".